# javascript - merge array on keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

Sorry if duplicate, but I can't find suitable answer. I have two arrays:

```
array1 = { '0': 'f1', '1': 'f2'};
array2 = { '0': 's1', '1': 's2'};
```

How to combine (merge) these two arrays to get something like this:

```
array3 = [['f1', 's1'], ['f2', 's2']];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your first examples are not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Did you mean to make two objects at first? `{ 0: 'f1', 1: 'f2' }`?

Comment: I accidentally forgot to add curly braces:

Comment: Guys, he just mocked up the data to give us an idea. That doesn't mean he is not using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

**If your inputs are arrays**

```
var a = ['f1', 'f2'];
var b = ['s1', 's2'];
```

The transformation you are looking for is a `zip`

```
var zip = (xs,ys)=>
  xs.reduce((zs,x,i)=>
    zs.concat([[x, ys[i]]]), []);

zip(a,b);
//=> [['f1', 's1'], ['f2', 's2']]
```

This assumes both inputs are the same length.

---

**If your inputs are objects** with numerical keys

```
var a = {'0': 'f1', '1': 'f2'};
var b = {'0': 's1', '1': 's2'};

var zipObj = (xs,ys)=>
  Object.keys(xs).reduce((zs,xk)=>
    zs.concat([[xs[xk], ys[xk]]]), []);

zipObj(a,b);
//=> [['f1', 's1'], ['f2', 's2']]
```

---

Despite you not having asked for it, to oblige Trey I've included **ES5** versions of the functions

```
"use strict";

// zip arrays
var zip = (xs,ys)=>
  xs.reduce((zs,x,i)=>
    zs.concat([[x, ys[i]]]), []);

// zip objects
var zipObj = (xs,ys)=>
  Object.keys(xs).reduce((zs,xk)=>
    zs.concat([[xs[xk], ys[xk]]]), []);
```

Comment: your ES5 section still uses arrow functions. Seems unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added the indexes in your question accidentally and are not working with some other data type... The simplest way is a for loop I imagine:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i in array1){
  newArray[i] = [array1[i], array2[i]];
}
```

Edit: This will work with objects or arrays of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the length of two arrays is equal, use the Trey's solution. Otherwise, use this:

```
var array3 = [];

l1 = array1.length;
l2 = array2.length;

len = (l1 > l2)? l2 : l1;

var array3 = [];

for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
  array3.push([array1[i],array2[i]));
}
```